# recycleview android for showing recipelist

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

im very new in android development but i have an assignment for showing recipe list like this
[click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbDly.png)

i was searching in youtube, search by keyword "recycleview" but just showing basic recycleview. i want a keyword for completing my assignment or some link for my study. if i click the recycleview list, it will show the description and image like that link i give.
please help me, thanks.
btw, why i cant post on stackoverflow with less word ? 
I just need the thing I mentioned

Comment: We can only help you when you show us some code.

Comment: You can learn how to make custom RecyclerView from [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/). Good Luck

Comment: @VikasTiwari are that recycleview can direct to another activity ?

Comment: Means, I can get what you want to ask @IffanZhafarHanafi